# Redis Pub/Sub Ack/Nack

Tags: go, redis, publish-subscribe

Is there a concept of acknowledgements in Redis Pub/Sub?

For example, when using RabbitMQ, I can have two workers running on separate machines and when I publish a message to the queue, only one of the workers will ack/nack it and process the message.

However I have discovered with Redis Pub/Sub, both workers will process the message.

Consider this simple example, I have this go routine running on two different machines/clients:

```
go func() {
    for {
        switch n := pubSubClient.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            process(n.Data)
        case redis.Subscription:
            if n.Count == 0 {
                return
            }
        case error:
            log.Print(n)
        }
    }
}()
```

When I publish a message:

```
conn.Do("PUBLISH", "tasks", "task A")
```

Both go routines will receive it and run the process function.

Is there a way of achieving similar behaviour to RabbitMQ? E.g. first worker to ack the message will be the only one to receive it and process it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis PubSub is more like a broadcast mechanism.

if you want queues, you can use [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) along with [RPUSH](http://redis.io/commands/rpush) to get the same interraction.  Keep in mind, RabbitMQ does all sorts of other stuff that are not really there in Redis.  But if you looking for simple job scheduling / request handling style, this will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up using, works as expected. I only needed this as an extra option for a broker for people who don't/can't use RabbitMQ with my library but AMQP is the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Redis streams (now, with Redis 5.0) support acknowledgment of tasks as they are completed by a group.

https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

Answer (score 2):

No, Redis' PubSub does not guarantee delivery nor does it limit the number of possible subscribers who'll get the message.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should stick to RabbitMQ then.

Comment: Granted - you should also review Redis' creator (Salvatore Sanfilippo) latest project, Disque, that is geared exactly for what you need (i.e. a distributed message queue): https://github.com/antirez/disque

Comment: It doesn't seem to be production ready. But yes I know about disque.

Comment: @RichardKnop they said the same about Linux ;)